# Migrating from Kinect SDK 1.8 to 2.0 unable to find windosPreview.Kinect.dll

Tags: windows, kinect, kinect-sdk

Im working on Kinect building a project of a virtual Mouse using the Kinect sensor with gestures.
But im facing problems while migrating to the new SDK 2.0 from SDK 1.8. As above mentioned im unable to find windowsPreview.Kinect.dll which contains most of functions for gesture controll in the v1.8 but its not there in v2.0

Answer (score 0):

Kinect SDK 1.8 and 2.0 are two completely different SDKs.

They use different ideas and API for gesture recognition capabilities, so if you are planning to reuse a library made for SDK 1.8, your only option is to rewrite the library yourself or find a newer version for the SDK 2.0.